# Referencing all table cells after a certain cell

Tags: jquery, html

How would I go about changing the cells in a table which follow a certain cell? I cannot get this to work with `.parent().nextAll()`, or `.index()`

My apologies, but I do not have any code to post. It is more of a general question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells aren't actually sequential in the HTML, so you can't just use everything at the same level (with `nextAll` or the like). Say you have this table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td id="two">two</td>
            <td>three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>four</td>
            <td>five</td>
            <td>six</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...and you want to highlight every cell "after" `two`, this would traverse and select those cells:

```
$('table td:gt(' + $('#two').index() + ')').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text()); // or whatever you want to do with the cell
});
```

Demo [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/utNNb/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but it gets the job done:

The basic strategy here is: (a) Select the siblings AFTER the current cell, (b) jump to the row element and for every row AFTER the current row, grab the TD elements and add to the siblings list.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><script src="../lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>
table { border:1px solid black; }
thead th { border-bottom:1px solid black; }
tfoot th { border-top:1px solid black; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {

    $('tbody').find('td')
        .click(function(event) {
            var $cell           = $(event.target),
                $siblings       = $cell.nextAll('td'),
                $remainingCells = $cell.closest('tr').nextAll().find('td');

            $siblings.add($remainingCells).each(function(index, element) {
                console.info(index + ':', $(element).text());
            });
        });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Alpha</td>
            <td>Bravo</td>
            <td>Charlie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Delta</td>
            <td>Echo</td>
            <td>Foxtrot</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Golf</td>
            <td>Hotel</td>
            <td>India</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Selecting all <td>s after <td id="i-want">
$('td#i-want ~ td')

// Selecting the next <td> after <td id="i-want">
$('td#i-want + td')
```

Comment: Doesn't `~` select only elements with the same parent - in this case, `<tr>`?